# Elastic : function_score on nested that match my query

Tags: elasticsearch, nested

I have documents indexed in Elastic like this (it's resumes) :

```
{
    id: 1
    title: 'Full Stack Developper',
    updatedAt: '2016-01-01'
    experiences: [
        {
            title: 'Java Software Engineer',
            endedAt: '2016-01-01'
        },
        {
            title: 'PHP Software Engineer',
            endedAt: '2008-01-01'
        },
    ]
}

{
    id : 2
    title: 'Backend Developper',
    updatedAt: '2016-01-01'
    experiences: [
        {
            title: 'Senior PHP Software Engineer',
            endedAt: '2016-01-01'
        },
        {
            title: 'Ruby On Rails advocate',
            endedAt: '2008-01-01'
        },
    ]
}
```

I would like to boost score for resume with XP ending in the last 5 years by eg and containing "PHP".

Is it possible to do this? (I don't see a way, but Elastic have a tons of capabilities!)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can `boost` the score of particular resumes matching certain conditions. You can combine [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-query.html) with [function score](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/query-dsl-function-score-query.html). This is a basic example

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "experiences",
          "score_mode": "sum",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "experiences.title": "php"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "range": {
                    "endedAt": {
                      "gte": "now-5y"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "boost": 5
    }
  }
}
```

This will give you desired results, I am using `score_mode:sum` so that candidate with multiple php experience get higher score.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I learnt things!

But am I right If i said that this will filter my search result with only experience with PHP in the title?

Because I would like to search on the whole CV (experiences, skills, ...) with a word PHP but have a boost when PHP is found on a experience ended less than 5 years ago.

Comment: Yes, you are right. This query will only give you results of people with 'php' in experiences.title and exp ended less than 5 years ago. I just gave a basic example as there was not much info in the question. you could wrap this query inside bool should clause with your basic query that searches for php in everything.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ChintanShah25 for your answer, it's really help me. Here a full request, that search for "java" everywhere and will increase document with the term "java" in experiences title by eg.
I use function_score because in my real case I have some function on it.

Hope it help (I'm not a Elastic expert, so if you see bad syntax feel free to add a comment ;) )

```
{
   "query": {
      "function_score": {
         "query": {
            "bool": {
               "must": {
                  "term": {
                     "_all": "java"
                  }
               },
               "should": [
                  {
                     "nested": {
                        "path": "experiences",
                        "score_mode": "sum",
                        "query": {
                           "bool": {
                              "should": [
                                 {
                                    "match": {
                                       "experiences.title": "java"
                                    }
                                 },
                                 {
                                    "range": {
                                       "experiences.start": {
                                          "gte": "now-5y"
                                       }
                                    }
                                 }
                              ]
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```